# How to limit API calls per second with angular2

Tags: rest, angular, angular-services

I have an API limit of 10 calls per second (however thousands per day), however, when I run this function (Called each Style ID of object, > 10 per second):

```
  getStyleByID(styleID: number): void {
    this._EdmundsAPIService.getStyleByID(styleID).subscribe(
      style => {this.style.push(style); },
      error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

from this function (only 1 call, used onInit):

```
  getStylesWithoutYear(): void {
    this._EdmundsAPIService.getStylesWithoutYear(this.makeNiceName, this.modelNiceName, this.modelCategory)
      .subscribe(
        styles => { this.styles = styles;
                      this.styles.years.forEach(year =>
                        year.styles.forEach(style =>
                          this.getStyleByID(style.id)));

        console.log(this.styles); },
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

It makes > 10 calls a second. How can I throttle or slow down these calls in order to prevent from getting a 403 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a pretty neat solution where you *combine two observables* with the [.zip() operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip):

1. An observable emitting the requests.
2. Another observable emitting a value every .1 second.

You end up with **one observable emitting requests every .1 second** (= 10 requests per second).

Here's the code ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wudehawaxa/1/edit?js,console)):

```js
// Stream of style ids you need to request (this will be throttled).
const styleIdsObs = new Rx.Subject<number>();

// Getting a style means pushing a new styleId to the stream of style ids.
const getStyleByID = (id) => styleIdsObs.next(id);

// This second observable will act as the "throttler".
// It emits one value every .1 second, so 10 values per second.
const intervalObs = Rx.Observable.interval(100);

Rx.Observable
  // Combine the 2 observables. The obs now emits a styleId every .1s. 
  .zip(styleIdsObs, intervalObs, (styleId, i) => styleId)
  // Get the style, i.e. run the request.
  .mergeMap(styleId => this._EdmundsAPIService.getStyleByID(styleId))
  // Use the style.
  .subscribe(style => {
    console.log(style);
    this.style.push(style);
  });

// Launch of bunch of requests at once, they'll be throttled automatically.
for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
  getStyleByID(i);
}
```

Hopefully you'll be able to translate my code to your own use case. Let me know if you have any questions.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Adam, there's also a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lesatebiwo/1/edit?js,console) showing how to throttle the requests if they don't come in consistently (see convo in the comments). It uses the `concatMap()` operator instead of the `zip()` operator.

Comment: This approach doesn't solve @Miguel's problem, unless the requests come in faster than they can be sent, consistently. For example, run your JSBin code, wait 5 seconds, then run this in the JSBin console: `for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {getStyleByID(i);}`. They will all fire at once, and will not throttle properly, because the unused intervals are being stored in the zip waiting to be used, instead of being discarded if they aren't used immediately.

Comment: Good catch, Adam! Only Miguel can tell if my suggestion would work in his case or not. If it doesn't, how would you make it bulletproof?

Comment: [Here's the JSBin of my solution.](http://jsbin.com/lesatebiwo/1/edit?js,console) The only downside is that every request is always delayed by 100m, including the first one. Feel free to edit your post with this solution if you think it's an improvement. I found the solution [here](http://www.g9labs.com/2016/03/21/lossless-rate-limiting-with-rxjs/)

Comment: Thank you, Adam. I have updated the answer with a link to your bin.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a timed `Observable` that triggers every n milliseconds. I didn't adapt your code but this one shows how it would work:

```
someMethod() {
  // flatten your styles into an array:
  let stylesArray = ["style1", "style2", "style3"];

  // create a scheduled Observable that triggers each second
  let source = Observable.timer(1000,1000);
  // use a counter to track when all styles are processed
  let counter = 0;

  let  subscription = source.subscribe( x => {
    if (counter < stylesArray.length) {
        // call your API here
        counter++;
    } else {
        subscription.complete();
    }
  });
}
```

Find here a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/DqMh3l1ubP0pDsaxhwo8) that shows it in action

Comment: When I try to run your plnkr, it errors on `boot/app`. `XHR error (404) loading https://run.plnkr.co/Zrc7pLEuNlmc8C0p/app/boot.ts`. I fixed it by changing `index.html` line 25 to `System.import('./app/boot')`

Answer (score 1):

While I didn't test this code, I would do try something along these lines.

Basically I create a variable that keeps track of when the next request is allowed to be made. If that time has not passed, and a new request comes in, it will use `setTimeout` to allow that function to run at the appropriate time interval. If the `delayUntil` value is in the past, then the request can run immediately, and also push back the timer by 100 ms from the current time.

```
delayUntil = Date.now();

getStylesWithoutYear(): void {
  this.delayRequest(() => {
    this._EdmundsAPIService.getStylesWithoutYear(this.makeNiceName, this.modelNiceName, this.modelCategory)
      .subscribe(
        styles => { this.styles = styles;
                    this.styles.years.forEach(year =>
                      year.styles.forEach(style =>
                        this.getStyleByID(style.id)));

        console.log(this.styles); },
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  };        
}

delayRequest(delayedFunction) {
  if (this.delayUntil > Date.now()) {
    setTimeout(delayedFunction, this.delayUntil - Date.now());
    this.delayUntil += 100;
  } else {
    delayedFunction();
    this.delayUntil = Date.now() + 100;
  }
}
```

Comment: `ERROR in styles.component.ts (47,9): Cannot find name 'delayUntil'.)
styles.component.ts (50,35): Cannot find name 'delayUntil'.)`

Comment: Fixed that, try copying the `delayRequest` method again.