# How to throttle requests when requests have varying parameters in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

- I'm implementing an api that another service offers.
- In my code I want to create some basic methods that ensure I follow the rules set by that other service.
- One of those rules is throttling at 10 requests per second.
- The service that requires throttling will have different query parameters on each service call

My approach to implementing this will have three pieces.

1. A component that requests the data from a service.
2. A service that formats the components request into potentially many service calls.
3. A basic api layer that makes the actual service call.

I've simplified my code here to show the issue more clearly.
Here's the service that fetches from the external api:
`basic-service.ts`

```
export class ApiService {
  throttle = 100 // 1 request per 100 milliseconds
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProductHistory(start_time): Observable<ProductHistory> {
    const url= "https://test.com&start=" + start_time;
    return this.http.get<ProductHistory>(url).pipe(throttleTime(this.throttle));
  }
}
```

Here's my service that knows how many requests to make
`product-history-service.ts`

```
export class ProductHistoryService{

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  getPriceHistory(): Observable<ProductHistory> {

    return new Observable<ProductHistory>(sub => {
      this.apiService.getProductHistory("1/1/2021").subscribe(result => sub.next(result));
      this.apiService.getProductHistory("1/2/2021").subscribe(result => sub.next(result));
      this.apiService.getProductHistory("1/3/2021").subscribe(result => sub.next(result));
    })
  }
}
```

Here's the component that would use the data
`component.ts`

```
export class BasicComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private productHistoryService: ProductHistoryService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}      

  fetchData() {
    this.productHistoryService.getPriceHistory()
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

This code runs, but doesn't throttle.  I suspect it has to do with `basic-service.ts` returning a new observable each time, but how can I reuse this observable if I need different query parameters?

[Edit:] Added a stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nzawcq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftest.ts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit API calls per second with angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260300/how-to-limit-api-calls-per-second-with-angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with my original solution is that I couldn't find a real way to make service calls with different parameters to share a single observable instance.
If I had found a solution under that approach I still would have been screwed because there wouldn't have been a way to separate different subscriptions for different components.

The correct answer lied in using an interceptor.
I created a simple interceptor as well as a simple semaphore service to keep track of requests per second.

I'm not going to post the psudocode because I don't want to rewrite my current implementation as I've spent a lot of time on this already.

Here's the simple service that allows for a maximum of 3 service calls per second

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThrottleService {

  constructor() { }
  private product_history_calls_in_the_last_second: number = 0;
  
  canMakeProductHistoryCall(): boolean {
    if (this.product_history_calls_in_the_last_second >= 3)
      return false;
    this.product_history_calls_in_the_last_second++;
    console.log("Going UP " + this.product_history_calls_in_the_last_second);
    setTimeout(() => { this.product_history_calls_in_the_last_second--; console.log("Going Down " + this.product_history_calls_in_the_last_second) }, 1000);
    return true;
  }
}
```

And here's the interceptor that utilizes the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ThrottleService } from '../services/throttle.service';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ThrottlerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private throttleService: ThrottleService) { }

  // Group 2 matches after domain and before query params
  product_history_regex = "(.com\\/)([\\/a-zA-Z-]+)(\\?*)"

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return from(this.handle(request, next));
  }

  async handle(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Promise<HttpEvent<unknown>> {

    if (request.url.match(this.product_history_regex)) {
      let groups = request.url.match(this.product_history_regex);
      let match = groups![2];
      if (match) {
        let arr = match.split('/');
        if (arr[0] == "products" && arr[2] == "candles") {
          if (this.throttleService.canMakeProductHistoryCall()) {
            return next.handle(request).toPromise();
          }
          else {
            await this.sleep(1000);
            return this.handle(request, next);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return next.handle(request).toPromise();
  }

  sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
}
```

This code is easy enough to modularize for different urls by creating your own regex
it also waits 1 second before trying again retry until a spot is free.

The beautiful part about this code is that hundreds of components can utilize the same simple `basic-service.ts` and none of them will step on each others subscriptions and they will all adhere to the throttle limit.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to move the throttle behavior to a subject and execute the api call from a subject

```
getProductHistory=new Subject()

  productHistory = this.getProductHistory.pipe(
    throttleTime(this.throttle),
    switchMap(start_time =>
      this.http
        .get('https://test.com&start=' + start_time)
        .pipe(catchError(e => of(e)))
    )
  );

//execution
setInterval(() => {
   getProductHistory.next("1/1/2021")
},1000)

//return result is available via subscribe or async pipe
productHistory.subscribe(res=>console.log(res))
```

Comment: I tried this implementing this solution last night, I couldn't figure out how to correctly pass `start_time` in.  I called getProductHistory.next() `N` times, but it only ever made one service call.

Comment: can u setup a stackbliz i can help debug

Comment: Added a stackblitz to the question

Comment: I have updated my answer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lxqyrp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftest.ts

You are testing your code in sync execution, therefore you can't see the effect of throttle, every `.next()` emit at the same moment. You can test with `setInterval`. I also change the productHistory stream a bit to handle error, so the stream won't complete on error.